# I2C sending data from arduino to python gives gibberish data

Tags: python, i2c, arduino

It's my first time working with `SMBUS` and I've read the docs of arduino and the `Wire` object. It states that I can send a string. To quote the docs: *string: a string to send as a series of bytes.* https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/wire/write/

When I convert my `int` to a `String` type and pass it along to `Wire.write`, I can't read it with Python.

Slave address: `0x8`

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(BaudRate); delay(10);
  Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS); 0x8
  Wire.onRequest(sendData); 
}

void loop() {
   sendData(1272); // right now hard-coded for testing purposes
}
// callback for sending data
void sendData(int data) {
    String dataString = String(data);
    int len = dataString.length() + 1;
    char charDataString[len];
    dataString.toCharArray(charDataString, len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        Serial.println(charDataString[i]); -> SHOWS THE CORRECT VALUES
        Wire.write(charDataString[i]);
    }
    delay(1000);
}
```

My python code (how I read the data):

```python
import smbus
import time
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
address = 0x8
while True:
    data = ""
    for (i in range(0, 10))
        ##BOTH VARIANTS DO NOT WORK
        data = bus.read_i2c_block_data(address, 99, 3)
        data += chr(bus.read_byte(address));

    print(data)
    time.sleep(1)
```

I can't wrap my head around what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: `I can't read it with Python` is meanigless ... what is actually read by the python program?

Comment: Some random numeric values which make no sense to me.

Comment: try converting the numbers to text using an online converter.

Comment: @SteveRobillard on the raspberry pi (when I receive the data?)

Comment: The Arduino sends it as bytes (as you state above) "string: a string to send as a series of bytes" so you need to convert the bytes back into a string. So if you send hello you might get "68 65 6c 6c 6f" as a hex representation or "104 101 108 108 111" as an ASCII representation. You can test this with an online converter type hex to text or ASCII to hex into google.

Comment: Could you update you question with actual values that are sent and received. What is the value sent by the Arduino? What is the value of the data received before you do the `chr`?